# Error when linking *.a and *.o files at llvm

Tags: c, gcc, clang, llvm

I have two static library files (.a) and one bitecode file (.bc) ,which created with an opt pass.In this bitecode file i have added my own code and in this code i need to call a function which is declared in the static libraries. I 've noticed that the llvm-ld tool no longer exists for clang newer versions so i tried  two different ways to link these three files (two libraries and one bitecode file):

**1.** try to link with gcc :

create with llc the object file of file.bc

```
$llc -filetype=obj file.bc -o file.o
```

link object and libs with gcc

```
$gcc -I  lib1.a lib2.a -O3 file.o -o file
```

these commands give me this error:

```
file.o: In function `main':
file.bc:(.text+0xc0): undefined reference to `function_in_lib'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

(function_in_lib is the function that i need to call from lib and compilers can't find this function)

**2.** the second way is with ld command

create with llc the object file of file.bc

```
 $llc -filetype=obj file.bc -o file.o
```

link object and libs with ld

`$ld -o linked lib1.a lib2.a file.o -lc`

these commands give me this error:

```
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 00000000004002b0
new.o: In function `main':
new.bc:(.text+0xc0): undefined reference to `function_in_lib'
```

i tried to change the order of arguments but i have more errors when i did it.I think that the fault become from the linking,any idea?

Comment: `$gcc -I  lib1.a lib2.a -O3 file.o -o file` should be changed to `$gcc -llib1.a -llib2.a -O3 file.o -o file`. gcc's `-I` parameter is to specify additional include paths.

Comment: when i try your suggestion format for the libraries ,this give me:

`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibtpc.a
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibregions.a
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: Oops, I failed at first comment :) Remove library suffixes and prefixes (`.a`, `.so` at the end and `lib` at the beginning of each library). Ensure they are available and placed into the right directory (usually, `/usr/lib/`)

Comment: these two libraries is not exist in `/usr/lib/` . And i have not the persmission to copy the files into here

Comment: then add the library directory by passing it with `-L` prefix to the linker through compiler command line arguments: `gcc file.o -o file -L/my/libraries/directory -ltpc -lregions`

Comment: hm ok, finally my fail was at the order of arguments and at missing flags when i compile the libraries and the object file.(threads and numas calls in libraries) thanks for your interest :)

Comment: Awesome. Have a good day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you're getting undefined references is because you're linking your libraries in the wrong way. A linker works in an incremental order - it looks at the first file you provided and gathers a list of things that file references but can't be found. Then the linker moves onto the next library and does the same thing, but also looks for opportunities to fix the undefined references from the previous libraries.

The reason that `ld` can't find `function_in_lib` is because it links `file.o` after the libraries and therefore doesn't get a chance to fill in the references that `file.o` requires. If you're looking for more specifics about linking and why you're running into this problem, [this](http://www.lurklurk.org/linkers/linkers.html) is a pretty good introduction.

If you just want to fix your problem, move the library files to after `file.o` in your command, i.e.

```
ld -o linked file.o lib1.a lib2.a -lc
```

Comment: as i wrote in my question i tried to change the format of the arguments and this give me more errors for undefined references which is about calls from the library. (the libraries is not mine at all.I must just use it to my project)

Comment: UPDATE:you were right @Matt ,my fail was the order of arguments and at missing flags when i compile libraries( about numa and threads,but this was my fault for this spesific situation) your answer was absolutely usefull for this problem. thanks for your answer..